# Three.js: Different lighting effect on different computer doing Multiple lights enviroment

Tags: three.js

I am using Three.js to do a multiple lights environment. I add 4 directional lights and 1 ambient light. It works great from my windows 7+Chrome computer, also another Mac desktop and a Macbook pro. But when I use another laptop to test it doesn't work. The laptop use same Windows 7 64-bits system and same chrome. But there is no lights at all at that laptop when the lights more than 2. It works fine when only have one light. I think maybe there are too many lights in there. Does anybody know what's the problem?

Comment: Most likely the laptop that has a different output has a inferior graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Each light consumes attribute and varying slots. Your laptop probably has so bad GPU that the maximum is breached with just two lights. Three.js also internally limits the amount of regular lights (to 4 IIRC), which can be overridden with `maxLights` parameter to `THREE.WebGLRenderer` constructor. That requires a decent GPU as well as drivers, though.